After customizing the legend, the exported PNG/PDF/SVG is incorrect
I used QgsPointClusterRenderer and embedded a QgsRuleBasedRenderer to modify the point layer. But when outputting the layout, it put the text and the set offset and other styles into the legend.





def add_points(layer_name: str, icon_name: str, point_name_prefix: str, points: list[tuple[float, float]],
               point_size: int = 5, icon_base64: str = "") -> QgsVectorLayer:
    """
    :param layer_name:
    :param icon_name:
    :param point_name_prefix:
    :param points:
    :param point_size:
    :param icon_base64: Base64 encoded image string
    :return:
    """
    # global pointLayer, options
    # Create vector layer
    point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:3857", layer_name, "memory")
    point_provider = point_layer.dataProvider()
    point_provider.addAttributes([
        QgsField("name", QtCore.QMetaType.Type(QtCore.QVariant.String), len=254),  # Ensure field name length does not exceed 254
        QgsField("type", QtCore.QMetaType.Type(QtCore.QVariant.String), len=254),
        QgsField("x", QtCore.QMetaType.Type(QtCore.QVariant.Double)),
        QgsField("y", QtCore.QMetaType.Type(QtCore.QVariant.Double))
    ])
    point_layer.updateFields()
    # Set coordinate transform
    crs_4326 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
    crs_3857 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857")
    transformer = QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_4326, crs_3857, project)
    # Start editing the vector layer
    point_layer.startEditing()
    # Transform and add points
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        transformed_point = transformer.transform(QgsPointXY(*point))
        feature = QgsFeature(point_layer.fields())
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(transformed_point))
        print(f"{point_name_prefix}{i + 1}", transformed_point.x(), transformed_point.y())
        feature.setAttributes([f"{point_name_prefix}{i + 1}", "point", transformed_point.x(), transformed_point.y()])
        point_provider.addFeature(feature)
    # Commit changes to the vector layer
    if point_layer.commitChanges():
        print("commit successed")
    else:
        print("commit failed：" + point_provider.error().message())
    # Save the vector layer to a GeoJSON file
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "GeoJSON"
    options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"

    # Define GeoJSON file path
    # geojson_path = 'D:/iProject/pypath/qgis-x/output/projects/MinJing_Points.geojson'
    geojson_path = f'{GEOJSON_PREFIX}/{layer_name}.geojson'
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(point_layer, geojson_path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
    # Load the GeoJSON file
    point_layer = QgsVectorLayer(geojson_path, layer_name, "ogr")
    if not point_layer.isValid():
        print("Failed to load the layer!")
        sys.exit(1)
    icon_path = f'{ICON_PREFIX}/{icon_name}.png'
    if icon_base64 != "":
        with open(icon_path, 'wb') as icon_file:
            icon_file.write(base64.b64decode(icon_base64))


    label_style = Dict()
    label_font_color = "#0000ff"
    label_style.font_family = "SimSun"
    label_style.font_size = 10
    label_style.font_color = label_font_color
    label_style.is_bold = True
    label_style.is_italic = False
    label_style.spacing = 0.0

    # create QgsRuleBasedRenderer 
    rule_symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
    rule_font_marker = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer(label_style.font_family)
    rule_font_marker.setSize(label_style.font_size)
    rule_font_marker.setColor(QtGui.QColor(label_style.font_color))
    rule_font_marker.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyCharacter, QgsProperty.fromExpression("name"))
    rule_font_marker.setOffset(QtCore.QPointF(0, -15))
    rule_raster_marker = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer(icon_path)
    rule_raster_marker.setSize(point_size)
    rule_symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, rule_raster_marker)
    rule_symbol.appendSymbolLayer(rule_font_marker)
    root_rule = QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule(None)
    rule = QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule(rule_symbol)
    rule.setFilterExpression("ELSE")  # Else rule
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)
    rule_renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(root_rule)

    # create QgsPointClusterRenderer 
    cluster_symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
    font_marker = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer(label_style.font_family)
    font_marker.setSize(label_style.font_size)
    font_marker.setColor(QtGui.QColor(label_style.font_color))
    font_marker.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyCharacter,
                                       QgsProperty.fromExpression("concat('(', @cluster_size, ')')"))
    font_marker.setOffset(QtCore.QPointF(0, -15))
    raster_marker = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer(icon_path)
    raster_marker.setSize(point_size)
    cluster_symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, raster_marker)
    cluster_symbol.appendSymbolLayer(font_marker)
    cluster_renderer = QgsPointClusterRenderer()
    cluster_renderer.setTolerance(10)
    cluster_renderer.setToleranceUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMillimeters)
    cluster_renderer.setClusterSymbol(cluster_symbol)
    # embed the RuleBasedRenderer
    cluster_renderer.setEmbeddedRenderer(rule_renderer)

    point_layer.setRenderer(cluster_renderer)

    point_layer.triggerRepaint()

    return point_layer

So, I wrote a custom legend method to filter out the redundant FontMarker from the custom symbol of the legend element.
def customize_legend(project, legend, legend_title):
    # Set the legend title
    legend.setTitle(legend_title)

    # Control which layers are included in the legend
    legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)  # Disable auto-update to manually control layers

    legend_model: QgsLegendModel = legend.model()
    root_group = legend_model.rootGroup()
    root_group.clear()

    layers = project.mapLayers().values()
    # Customize the appearance of legend items
    for map_layer in layers:
        if map_layer.name() not in ["BaseTile", "MainTile"]:
            # root_group.addLayer(vector_layer)
            layer_custom_type = get_type(map_layer)
            if layer_custom_type == "":
                continue
            layer_renderer = map_layer.renderer()
            legend_symbol_items = layer_renderer.legendSymbolItems()
            for tr in root_group.children():
                if layer_custom_type == "point" and tr.layerId() == map_layer.id():
                    # custom symbol
                    for legend_symbol_item in legend_symbol_items:
                        symbol: QgsMarkerSymbol = legend_symbol_item.symbol()
                        symbol_layers = symbol.symbolLayers()
                        filtered_symbol_layers = []
                        for symbol_layer in symbol_layers:
                            if symbol_layer.layerType() != "FontMarker":
                                filtered_symbol_layers.append(symbol_layer.clone())
                        filtered_marker_symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol(filtered_symbol_layers)
                        legend_symbol_item.setSymbol(filtered_marker_symbol)
                        symbol_legend_node = QgsSymbolLegendNode(tr, legend_symbol_item)
                        symbol_legend_node.setCustomSymbol(filtered_marker_symbol)
                        QgsMapLayerLegendUtils.setLegendNodeCustomSymbol(tr, 0, filtered_marker_symbol)
            root_group.addLayer(map_layer)
    legend.refresh()


Finally, I opened the generated qgz file with QGIS, and it looked correct, there is no problem if you export through the QGIS layout interface. But, in the PyQGIS the only problem is that when exporting PNG/PDF/SVG, it still carries the FontMarker that has not been filtered out.
Export code:
def export_layout_to_image(layout, output_path):
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
    settings.dpi = 300
    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        print(f"delete file {output_path}")
        FileUtil.delete_file(output_path)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"delete file {output_path} failed: {e}")
        pass

    if os.path.exists(output_path):
        print(f"delete file {output_path} failed")
        return

    print(f"Starting export image to {output_path}...")
    result = exporter.exportToImage(output_path, settings)

    if result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
        print(f"Layout exported successfully to {output_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to export layout to {output_path}, result code: {result}")
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"execution time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")

this is export png:

